# UITableViewCell Subclass - Adding a subview on IBAction

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add a subview to the `UIViewController`'s view when the `UITableViewCell`'s button inside the view is triggered. The problem im facing is to call the parentview from the table view cell's subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup parent `tableView` in view hierarchy:

```
-(UITableView*) parentTableView
{
    UIView* v = [self superview];
    while (v && ![v isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        v = [v superview];
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the tableviewcell subclass, pass it a pointer to the instance of the parentview by making your own init method. Then save that pointer in your subclass as an instance variable. That way you can do what ever you want to the parent when something happens in the subclass. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Can elaborate more on this? Like some example? Cos i need to make sure i can get the indexpath.row value. Some sample on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to set the `UIViewController` the delegate for the `UITableViewCells`. You have to create a protocol and make the `UIViewController` implement it. Furthermore you need to subclass `UITableViewCell` in order to add the delegate property.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol YourTableViewCellDelegate

  - (void)didTouchButton:(UIButton *)theButton;

@end
```

In the action method for the `UIButton` check for the existence of the delegate:

```
if (self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didTouchButton:)]) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(didTouchButton:) withObject:_theButton];
}
```